# Angular: Can't import Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, sequelize.js

In my app, i can't import `sequelize` . here is error

> chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.02 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 691 bytes
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map
>   (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.js,
>   styles.js.map (styles) 9.77 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {vendor}
>   vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered] Date:
>   2020-04-16T08:48:36.690Z - Hash: 4a99c396b1a12d42e229 - Time: 5586ms
>
> ERROR in node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts:345:5 - error
>   TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> 345   | Buffer // literal value
>           ~~~~~~ node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts:354:24 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type
>   definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
>   the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> 354   | (string | number | Buffer | WhereAttributeHash)[]; // implicit
>   [Op.or]
>                              ~~~~~~ node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts:1371:44 - error TS2591:
>   Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for
>   node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field
>   in your tsconfig.
>
> 1371 export type Identifier = number | string | Buffer;
>                                                   ~~~~~~ node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/utils.d.ts:58:26 - error TS2503:
>   Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.
>
> 58 export function stack(): NodeJS.CallSite[];
>                               ~~~~~~
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

My code is too simple, i only called connection string, nothing more than that

**posts.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres:1@localhost:3000/test1');


@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

Please point out what's wrong?
[ i was trying something like this: https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/getting-started/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize is for server-side, not for client. You should use it from Nodejs backend.

Comment: I'm new to this. Can you give me a example or tutorial?

Comment: @Frost You need to write s server side application using nodejs. Angular is a client side application . Search google fro crud apis using sequelize